# Raspbian Wheezy Owncloud and NFS together

Tags: linux, raspbian, nfs, owncloud

I am trying to setup a file/DLNA server on raspberry pi (raspbian wheezy) for the files to be shared by all the devices I use - android and Linux to the minimum.

I have a USB drive with some decent storage where I have all my files. So far, I had NFS and dlna serving the USB drive contents.

Recently, I installed owncloud. It required the owncloud data directory to be owned by www-data. I have mounted (from fstab) the USB drive with options `rw,user,uid=33,gid=33,mask=007`. The owncloud worked fine (though it is very slow to render the contents).

My nfs exports is as follows:

```
/owncloud_data/mystuff *(rw,all_squash,anonuid=33,anongid=33,no_subtree_check)
```

My shomount -e localhost displays the following:

```
Export list for localhost:
/owncloud_data/mystuff (everyone)
```

However, when I issue

```
sudo mount localhost:/owncloud_data/mystuff /my_nfs
```

I get the following error:

```
mount.nfs: access denied by server while mounting localhost:/owncloud_data/mystuff
```

I don't understand why. I kind of guess that this is because the /owncloud_data/mystuff is owned by the www-data. But, the nfs-server is run as root; should it not be able to read the data? Or am I missing anything in this regard? I dont get any useful logs in the /var/log/messages; I tried including the `--debug all` option in the nfs config.

I haven't started with the dlna yet (I have installed minidlna which was working with NFS before I installed the owncloud).

OR, is there a better solution for what I am trying to do?

Please let me know if you need more information in this regard.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I wont tick this as an answer. It is a work around.

The problem is if I export the /owncloud_data/mystuff the nfs mount is not working. If I export all /owncloud_data, it is working fine (along with the export options I have mentioned in the original post). I just mount /owncloud_data/mystuff on the client side (though technically I can mount /owncloud_data there).

I will be happy if anybody can explain this behaviour and solve to export /owncloud_data/mystuff.